# java thread terminating early and suspiciously

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code in a Runnable that gets passed to a thread t:

```
public void run() {
        logger.debug("Starting thread " + Thread.currentThread());

        try {
            doStuff();
        } catch (Exception e) {
         logger.debug("Exception in Thread " + Thread.currentThread());
        } 

        logger.debug("End of thread " + Thread.currentThread());
    }
```

I've hit a bug where I see deadlock with the following conditions

- only the start of thread message has been printed by my logs
- A thread dump shows that the thread t (supposed to be executing this) is no longer running

Is there some magical way this thread could have terminated early without either logging an end of thread message OR throwing an exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure that `doStuff()` did not throw an `Error`? Change `catch (Exception e)` to `catch (Throwable t)`. It's possible to kill threads in Java with `Thread.stop()`, but that is highly unlikely.

Comment: thanks much. Turns out the thread was OOMing -- and since I wasn't catching throwable (and perhaps other logging was misconfigured?), I didn't get any notification

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that where you **start()** the Thread, you also **join()** it afterwards?

```
Runnable myRunnable=new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
    // your original code goes here
  }
};

Thread myThread=new Thread(myRunnable);

myThread.start();

myThread.join(); // magic happens here! it waits for the thread to finish ;)
```

By the way, **join()** may throw an **InterruptedException**,
so if something interrupts your thread while it's running, 
join will inform you about this by throwing this exception.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

When you catch `Exception`, you will catch any `RunnableException` and any declared thrown `Exception`, but you will not catch anything that extends `Error`.  If you truly want to catch **any**thing, then you need to catch `Throwable`.

If you want to do this for logging purposes only and you don't care why the Thread exits, you can do this:

```
public void run() {
  logger.debug("Starting thread " + Thread.currentThread());
  try {
    // The work of your Thread
  } finally {
    logger.debug("End of thread " + Thread.currentThread());
  } 
}
```

and the `finally` statement is guaranteed to execute unless the Thread is stopped or deadlocks or in some other way stops executing without an Exception.

In most of my programs, I install an [UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) so that I'll know about every Thread that dies unexpectedly.  It's been a tremendous help in tracking failures.  This was added to the language as of Java 5.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the thread could get interrupted after the end of the `try/catch` block but before the last `logger.debug` statement. In that case it would throw an `InterruptedException` that, in principle, might not get recorded anywhere (if the default exception handler is set to ignore such things).

That seems like a rather unlikely scenario, though... it's kind of hard to tell what's going on without knowing more about the rest of your program, though.

Comment: Assuming interruptible I/O on the logger.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you trap a general exception I suggest you log it so you know what the exception was and it cause.  Failing to do so will not help you at all.